# Regular expression for Text, Numbers and Decimals

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-search-lucene, analyzer

I am trying to get a regular expression for text, decimals and decimal numbers. The expression must match all at once.

The main problem is that I had to write an Analyzer for Zend_Search_Lucene in order to be able to search for decimal digits. Right now I can only search for texts and numbers. So I guess it to match decimal numbers to make them tokens and thus the regular expression in question.

Answer (score 3):

Okay now i feel stupid but anyways. I finally got what I wanted. This, [a-zA-Z0-9.]+ did the trick. imagine how short that was.